# Connecting/Attaching application to browser?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Is it possible to allow my program to attach to a browser (IE, Firefox or Chrome) and get the current Source of a certain tab (Defined by a url)?

I would also need to get the `html` from the page every (x) seconds since the page will most likely be dynamic.

Also, if it's possible, have some sort of `WaitBrowserFinish` or something similar to wait for the browser to actually load its contents.

I am not wanting to use the `WebBrowser` Control, because I would like the user to use their own browser.

**Question:** Is this possible? If possible, how would I go about doing it?

**UPDATE:**

I found [THIS](https://markcz.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/automating-chrome-browser-from-csharp/) and I am currently looking at it. However i would like for the user to use their default browser (since I don't actually know if they have `Chrome`, `Firefox` installed) I would not mind however, if everything went through IE (since everyone `should` have it).

Comment: Downvoter, want to explain what I'm not clear on? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible I guess you would need to build an extension for the web browser for a good result, and then the user would need to install it in the browser. Even if you did that I guess the extension could be sandboxed by the browser and not allow communication with anything outside of the process.

For Chrome see [Extensions Get Started](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)

I have built applications before that use 'screen scraping' for web browsers, but this would only get the rendered content, not the source and would require the user to determine when the page has finished loading.

Comment: I am implementing this is a software. A Chrome extension would not help. And you are correct, i am looking for the `rendered` content, not the actual source.

Comment: Ah I see, your question says you want the source.

Comment: Correct, however getting the source every `(x)` seconds would mean something similar. I changed the wording though. Thanks.

Comment: The way I did it was to find the window and then locate the control that hosts the web page and examine the content. The process was triggered by the user clicking a button. Unfortunately I don't have any code sampes for it.